# boost: how to specify specific msvcrt.lib while building boost test

Tags: visual-c++, boost, msvcrt, boost-test, msvc12

I am trying to build boost with specific msvcrt.lib file used for building other project. I didn't find flag or config section, where I can control this lib.

by default boost uses what is installed on machine. is there a way to overwrite this with specific msvcrt.lib file?